# How can i make this dynamically input field drop down without coming in the middle of others

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, types, submit

I have created the input fields but when i click the first two ,it does well until when i request the third which comes between the first two and also other also comes between.can some help me please.
here is my javascript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // it to after "after-add-more" div class.
  $(".add-more").click(function() {
    var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
    $(".after-add-more").after(html);
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="input-group control-groups after-add-more-inputs">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="add-more-inputs">
    <a href="#">Add</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Copy Fields -->
  <div class="copy-field hide">
    <div class="control-groups input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
      <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;"> 
      <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
      <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
      <div class="remove">
        <a href="#"> Remove</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm really trying hard to understand your question.

Comment: do you mean **How can you add new input set/row after last row ?**

Comment: check: class="add-more-inputs" and the ".after-add-more"

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/tfx6grxn/1/

```js
$(".add-more-inputs a").click(function() {
  $('.copy-field').before($(".copy-field").html());
});

$("body").on("click", ".remove a", function() {
  $(this).closest(".control-groups").remove();
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="input-group control-groups after-add-more-inputs">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="add-more-inputs">
    <a href="#">Add</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Copy Fields -->
  <div class="copy-field hide">
    <div class="control-groups input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
      <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;"> 
      <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
      <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
      <div class="remove">
        <a href="#"> Remove</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Third insert will happen after second element position.

Used `jQuery` `before` method, on **.copy-field**. It's will insert new elements before **.copy-field**.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Wawoooooo. You the best of the best.thanks so much.it work really well.i will be so glad if you continue helping me.thanks

Comment: I wanted to me with another thing.How can i extend the properties of one field to another dynamically input field.i mean if am asking a birth year and i provide a bootstrap calender year,it should be extended to other input fields.

Comment: @n.ssendawula .Didn't get you. Can you please explain me what you are looking for? Property means attribute?

Comment: Thanks.i mean how can make make the hidden fields also to display a bootstrap calender as it is in the input fields which are not hidden. THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: Can you create a `jsfiddle` with `bootstrap-datepicker` in one of the input textbox. Please update the question accrodingly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // it to after "after-add-more" div class.
  $(".add-more-inputs a").click(function() {
    var html = $(".copy-field").html();
   
    $(this).after(html);
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {

    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="input-group control-groups after-add-more-inputs">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
    <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="add-more-inputs">
    <a href="#">Add</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Copy Fields -->
  <div class="copy-field hide">
    <div class="control-groups input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
      <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;"> 
      <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
      <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" style="width:30%;">
      <div class="remove">
        <a href="#"> Remove</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks but the only problem is that the input fields don't follow each other well.when i click the third one,it occupies the middle of the first two.and when i click the next also occupies the second place.for sure am somehow confused.can you please help me sir

Comment: Surely, I'd help you. Please be more clear about your need.